# Delete lines from log files and update existing file without the lines

Tags: shell

For some development work I need to remove some "noise" from a series of Log files all stored in a folder. (I have this on Linux, but can also do this in Windows.) A line that I want to remove would look like this:

```
Sep 5/2017 23:59:50:324 [MISC   ]: ValueType:ST / SetId: / ObID:0002-d007^RhySta^MDIL / ObSubID:0 / Detail:Sinus Rhythm / Units: / AccessChecks: / ObxTimeStamp:
```

Anytime I see `[MISC   ]:` I want to remove the whole line and leave nothing in its place. As soon as lines are deleted from the file I want to move to save the file with existing name, and then move to the next file in the folder.

I am not a scripter.. thus the request for assistance.

Comment: use `for` + `sed` + `mv`. Good luck

Comment: I understand that you're not a scripter, but this is basically a request for someone else to write code for you. You're going to have to attempt it yourself. If you write a script and have questions about how to finish it, that's where we can help.

Comment: Ignore the part about working on multiple files.  Write a script that does what you want with one file, then use `find` or a loop to invoke that script on each file.  Be wary of inadvertently looping over files you are creating.  Simplest solution (possibly) would be to create new output files in a different directory and then delete the originals when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one to do it using  `for, find, sed and mv.` .

Sample dir:

```
[zee]$ find . 
./test2/file1.tx
./test2
```

One-liner:

```
 [zee]$ for file in $(find test1/ -type f) ; do  echo "checking if file $file has a match" ; grep -q "MIS" $x ; if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then  echo "$file has a match" ;  sed -i '/MIS/d' $file && echo "deleted matches...moving $file"  && mv $file test2/ ;  fi ; done
```

Output of running the above one-liner:

```
checking if file test1/file1.tx has a match
test1/file1.tx has a match
deleted matches...moving test1/file1.tx
```

Here is what it does: find all files in directory "test1", checks if a given file has a match. If the file has a match, it removes the match(s) and move the file to directory "test2".